# How can I save the multiselect dropdown list?

Tags: magento-1.9

I had inserted the values in my form. When we select the values the selected values are not saving.
How can I save the selected values?

Comment: Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

The table field/attribute corresponding to your field should be of type `text` and you should change the array sent through post to string (`implode(',', $values)`) and then save it.